# What possible reasons could there be for a checkbox on an item becoming unchecked in the web DB?

Tags: multilingual, templates, fieldtype

We have a specific component that includes a checkbox. There are multiple items of this component. The checkbox on these items becomes sporadically unchecked in the web DB, without the items having been edited in or published from the master DB. 
Scopewise, it can affect any item of the same type, but when the issue occurs it doesn't necessarily affect all items of the type.

The checkbox field is shared, there is no standard value associated with it. There is no default value specified on the template field item.

The template for the component exists in English (en) only, the components in multiple langauges.

The issue seems to occur on recycles, independently of there being a deployment.

Comment: Did said checkbox change status from unversioned/versioned/shared recently?

Comment: No, the template field item doesn't show any edits since 2015. We have recently migrated from 7.2 - 8.2 but the issue was already reported in 7.2 (though very occasional)

Comment: I would still check `VersionedFields` and `UnversionedFields` tables in SQL, for any occurrences of the `FieldID` of your affected field. There should be 0 rows.

Comment: Which update or Sitecore 8.2 do you use?

Comment: Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170728)

Comment: There was similar bug before 8.2 update 1: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update1/Release%20Notes
`Checkbox values get erased when you navigate from an item with unsaved changes​. 107694`. But you're on newer version. I had similar issue once on 8.2 update 3 and haven't found the answer. So if you do find, please share it here :)

Comment: Interesting, I'll ask if there's more detail. Doesn't sound exactly like what we have, as the values are erased in the web but not master, so nobody should be navigating to the items in the content editor.

Comment: I had a similar problem and already asked a question regarding same. Did you get chance to have a look at the question below: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/8782/1671

Comment: @AmitabhVyas - thanks, I hadn't seen the question but Marek pointed out the issue in a comment above. I don't think this is exactly our issue, as our field values get erased in the web DB, where no editors are working. These components are also pretty old and shouldn't have been edited for a couple of years now.

Comment: Ok and are you noticing such behavior every time or its random?

Comment: Fairly random. Possibly after unplanned recycles (investigating a Castle Windsor linked memory leak at the moment)

Comment: Ya, We ended up raising a support ticket for the same and Sitecore provided a installation patch. Although that specific scenario was fixed it later releases.